# R-generate private Key from Fingerprint - android signature

Tags: android

im using

```
androiddebugkey, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 68:1F:B8:80:C0:B9:96:D1:6E:95:86:69:CD:DB:0E:28:DC:9E:89:51
```

is there a way to reverese  and generate private key from fingerprint to sgin andriod new release with correct key that in production play store ,

Comment: If there _was_ a way to do this, do you think there would be even a tiny bit of value to using encryption with this standard?

Answer (score 3):

No.

Hashing is by definition one way only.